# Creation of a Select in a View

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in a VIEW:

```
<select name="selected_budget_mode" class="" onchange="OnBudgetModeChanged(this)">
<option value="0"
        <% if params[:current_budget_mode].to_i == 0 %>selected
        <% end %>><%= show_budget_mode(0) %></option>
<option value="1"
        <% if params[:current_budget_mode].to_i == 1 %>selected
        <% end %>><%= show_budget_mode(1) %></option>
<option value="2"
        <% if params[:current_budget_mode].to_i == 2 %>selected
        <% end %>><%= show_budget_mode(2) %></option>
</select>
```

I am aware of the [`select_tag` and the `options_for_select` form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags), but that implies that I need to create a list with the options and then pass it to the `options_for_select`.

The `budgets_mode` are not dynamic. They don't come from calling a service or other function, there are only 3 modes.

What would be the best approach to simplify this code and make it as readable as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could still use `options_for_select` without much hassle:

```
<%= options_for_select (0..2).map { |i| [show_budget_mode(i), i] }, params[:current_budget_mode].to_i %>
```

Of course, I'd recommend creating the array in the controller or a helper, rather than the view. The view should ideally do as little logic as possible.

Alternatively, you could use `content_tag` just the keep the code cleaner:

```
<% (0..2).each do |i| %>
  <%= content_tag :option, show_budget_mode(i), selected: params[:current_budget_mode].to_i == i %>
<% end %>
```

Again, I'd recommend moving stuff to the controller. Even a `current_budget_mode` helper method would help clean things up:

```
class SomeController < ActionController
  helper_method :current_budget_mode, :budget_modes

  def current_budget_mode
    params[:current_budget_mode].to_i
  end

  def budget_modes
    (0..2).to_a
  end
end
```

which would clean up the view:

```
<% budget_modes.each do |i| %>
  <%= content_tag :option, show_budget_mode(i), selected: current_budget_mode == i %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<%= options_for_select budget_modes.map { |i| [show_budget_mode(i), i] }, current_budget_mode %>
```